# How to simulate a button press of a dualshock 3 pad from a raspberry

Tags: python, c, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

here is the situation: I have a raspberry pi, connected with a bluetooth dongle and a dualshock ps3 controller.

I would like to:

- catch all bluetooth stacks sent by the controller
  (exemple: I press x on the controller and I get on my console the "message" the controller sends to the ps3)
- be able to write a script telling the raspberry pi to send that message to the ps3, so getting rid of the controller.

Do you know if someone already worked on it? I only read about retropie wich allows you to use dualshock to play on raspberry and although it proofs that a communication is possible, is not my task

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of catching the controller button presses with the raspberry pi, I would take a look at these projects :

http://dhoium3009.wordpress.com/raspberry-pi-connecting-multiple-ps3-controllers-via-bluetooth/
http://www.raspians.com/Knowledgebase/ps3-dualshock-controller-install-on-the-raspberry-pi/

For the second part, this might be a bit trickier. I don't know exactly if a simple replay of the stacks works. Anyway, to read and send stacks, I would take a look at the `bluez` library and it's python wrapper [python-bluez](https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/). Here is an example (although for another kind of usage):

http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Bluetooth-InOut-Board-or-Whos-Hom/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it! Why a simple replay won't work in your opinion? since I send the same message?

Comment: I don't know, maybe the messages use some sort of session key or dynamic controller id that may change after each restart. But again, I'm just speculating, it could very well work fine! Anyway good luck with your project, it seems awesome :)!

Comment: Yes it is :) I'll begin today

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if you consider this a closed subject.

Comment: @Michele Were you able to do your project? I'm thinking  about doing this.